# Inner join switch to outer, invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, inner-join, outer-join

So I was playing around with a few join queries, and I noticed some unusual behaviour, when I switch my query from an inner to an outer join, and leave everything else the same, I get an error, below are the two queries running.

```
SELECT Staff.Fname AS "First Name", Staff.Lname AS "Second Name", Booking_ID
FROM Staff INNER JOIN Booking ON Staff.StaffID = Booking.StaffID;
```

[image: A screenshot of an SQL Query returning successfully]

And then when I switch it around,

```
SELECT Staff.Fname AS "First Name", Staff.Lname AS "Second Name", Booking_ID
FROM Staff OUTER JOIN Booking ON Staff.StaffID = Booking.StaffID;
```

I get `Error ORA-00904 Invalid identifier "Staff"."StaffID"`.

I thought the above query should return all staff who have made a booking along with the bookingid, as well as all those who haven't made a booking.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you switch it back to INNER JOIN, does the query still work?

Comment: is there a reason you need an outer join for this data?  Also seeing the table structure of both tables might help

Comment: Yeah the Query still works when switched back Joseph.

Comment: I suppose there are other ways to ask this query but I'm interested in why this particular query would not work Marshall.

Comment: also, you should have a table in front of Booking_ID just for clarity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you need to state `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (or FULL or RIGHT) instead of `OUTER JOIN`.  Oracle is seeing `OUTER` in your SQL as a table alias.  That is, it's reading it as:

```
SELECT Staff.Fname AS "First Name", Staff.Lname AS "Second Name", Booking_ID
  FROM Staff foo 
        JOIN Booking ON Staff.StaffID = Booking.StaffID;
```

Although it would look strange, this would actually work:

```
SELECT OUTER.Fname AS "First Name", OUTER.Lname AS "Second Name", Booking_ID
  FROM Staff OUTER JOIN Booking ON OUTER.StaffID = Booking.StaffID;
```

Oracle would see this as a simple inner join between the STAFF table (aliased as OUTER), and BOOKING.

Essentially, `OUTER` is a *keyword* but not a *reserved* word in Oracle.  That is, it has special meaning but can still be used as an alias.

Comment: The fix is to use FULL OUTER JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of OUTER JOIN, depending on how exactly he meant to use outer join.  Oracle SQL is so much fun

Comment: Well spotted, I'll accept this as the answer once it lets me (4 minutes). I was wondering why google was throwing up so many alias related questions when I was looking this up!

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Yes, you're right.  I was just thinking LEFT.  I updated my answer to include FULL and OUTER.